# Indefinite article in question answer with the same singular countable noun

Tags: articles

Text is

> Is this a pen? - No, it is not a pen.

Why do we use indefinite article in the second case instead of definite article before pen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person 1: Do you want **an** apple?

Person 2: Yes, I want **an** apple.

Person 1: OK, you can have **the apple** that is on the table, not **the one** on the couch.

"the" is specific. Wanting a thing or not wanting a thing is not specific. It is only afterwards that **a thing** can become or does become **the thing**.

He has **a** large freckle on his nose. **The** freckle has been there for ages.